# How to count records of Dataset using SSRS report expression

Tags: reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008

I need to get count of the records of the `dataset`, where its `AsssistTypeId  = 1`.

My Dateset is something like this,

```
+---------+--------+---------------+
| LobbyID | ProdID | AsssistTypeId |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285316  | 160    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285317  | 161    | 2             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285318  | 159    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285319  | 160    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285331  | 160    | 2             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285332  | 160    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285333  | 161    | 2             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285334  | 160    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285335  | 160    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285335  | 161    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 285335  | 163    | 1             |
+---------+--------+---------------+
```

Currently I'm get count of the `lobbyId` distinct value as follows and it's working as expected.according to the above `dataset`, output for the following expression returns **9**

```
=iif(inscope("matrix1_RowGroup3"), 
IIF(Count(Fields!LobbyID.Value) = 0, "", Count(Fields!LobbyID.Value)),
iif(inscope("matrix1_AssistedBy"),IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!LobbyID.Value) = 0, "", CountDistinct(Fields!LobbyID.Value)),
CountDistinct(Fields!LobbyID.Value)))
```

Now I need to get count of the `LobbyId` where its `AsssistTypeId  = 1`. For the above dataset, I'm expecting `AsssistTypeId  = 1` count as **6** ,How can I write expression for this?

**Updated: 12/8/2020**

This is what I tried, but it doesn't return any result.

```
=
iif
(

    inscope("matrix1_RowGroup3"),   
        IIF
        (
            Fields!AsssistTypeId.Value = 1,
            IIF
            (
                Count(Fields!LobbyID.Value) = 0, "", Count(Fields!LobbyID.Value)            
            ),
            Nothing         
        ),
        IIF
        (
            inscope("matrix1_AssistedBy"),
            
            IIF
            (
                Fields!AsssistTypeId.Value = 1,
                IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!LobbyID.Value) = 0, "", CountDistinct(Fields!LobbyID.Value)),
                Nothing         
            ),
            IIF
            (
                Fields!AsssistTypeId.Value = 1,
                CountDistinct(Fields!LobbyID.Value),
                Nothing         
            )
        )
)
```

And I also tried this,

```
=iif(inscope("matrix1_RowGroup3"), 
IIF(Count(Fields!LobbyID.Value) = 0, "", Count(Fields!LobbyID.Value)),
iif(inscope("matrix1_AssistedBy"),IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!AsssistTypeId.Value = 1,1,0)) = 0, "", SUM(IIF(Fields!AsssistTypeId.Value = 1,1,0))),
SUM(IIF(Fields!AsssistTypeId.Value = 1,1,0))))
```

**This works**, but when there have duplicates `LobbyId`, Its also count that Duplicates, According to the above data set, output shows as, **8** , But its should be **6**

Comment: =SUM(IIF(Fields!AsssistTypeId = 1, 1, 0))   You may need the dataset name in there if there's more than 1 dataset. Where is this expression going? Header, footer? You may want to think of adding a computed field in the dataset... with the expression, IIF(Fields!AsssistTypeId = 1, 1, 0), then just sum on that field in your report.

Comment: @SS_DBA. The OP actually wants the number of distinct `LobbyID` where `AssistTypeID` =1 as they state the answer should be 6. I agree with you that this would be much easier to do in the dataset query.

Comment: @AlanSchofield have any possible way to do this without using dataset query sir? I'm new to this and bit confused all. can I do this using another `countDistinct`?

Comment: @SS_DBA Can I do this with using expression without using dataset query ? is there any possible way to do this using `countDistinct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested but you could try...

```
=CountDistinct
    (
      IIF (
           Fields!AssistTypeId.Value = 1
           , Fields!LobbyID.Value
           , Nothing
          ) 
    , "matrix1_RowGroup3"
    )
```

As CountDistinct ignores null (nothing) values, we replace anything that is not the value you want to count with `Nothing` then do a distinct count of LobbyID from the remaining values.

You may have to change or remove the `"matrix1_RowGroup3"` scope, I just guessed what it might be from you existing expression. I also assumed AsssistTypeID was a typo and removed an 's'.

Comment: Sir, you code did not work for me, So i tried another one, please look on my updated question.

Comment: Edit your question and show the report design, PLEASE INCLUDE the row group details from the row groups panel below the main design window.

Comment: Sir can you please check my updated one. I tried another expression as well, but its count duplicates,

Comment: I've provided an answer that, based on hte info you provided, should work as proved by the screen shot. If it does not work, please post the report design including row group names and settings

Comment: As i said in m,y answer you may have to change the scope. Looking at your design, it lokos ike the expression sits in the "matrix1_AssistedBy" scope, so change it to that and try again. In fact you may be able to remove the the  `, "matrix1_RowGroup3"` line altogether. If you remove it, the epxression will be evaluated in the scope that it sits in.

Comment: Yes it's working after adding `matrix1_AssistedBy` instead of `matrix1_RowGroup3`. Thanks sir :)